# Removing source dependencies after building from source

Tags: compiling, dependencies

Now while installing the dependencies I've realized that they actually take up quite a lot of space (depending on what the dependencies are). So my question is:

- How do I remove all of the dependency files which my operating system does not require? Is `sudo apt-get autoremove` enough?

Comment: Please not that you can just [edit] your question. there's no need to write a similar one (this) and delete the old question. This leads just to confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Were the dependencies also compiled from source or where they installed using `apt`?

Comment: @ByteCommander Didn't realize people were so fast here ;) Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `apt-get autoremove` is the command to use; it'll remove dependencies that were installed automatically and are no longer required.

You can choose during removal of a program to remove the dependencies at the same time with `apt-get remove --auto-remove packagename`.

You can also use [Bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux) - it does the following:

> BleachBit deletes unnecessary files to free valuable disk space, maintain privacy, and remove junk. Rid your system of old clutter including cache, cookies, Internet history, localizations, logs, temporary files, and broken shortcuts. Designed for Linux systems, it wipes clean Adobe Reader, APT, Bash, Beagle, Chromium, Epiphany, Firefox, Flash, GIMP, Google Earth, Java, KDE, OpenOffice.org, Opera, RealPlayer, Second Life viewer, Skype, VIM, XChat, Yum, and more.

Probably what you're looking for...

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `apt-get remove --autoremove packagename` or `apt-get autoremove packagename` take into account packages not installed but whose dependencies were built using `apt-get build-dep packagename`?

Comment: I have hundreds of dependencies. It is not sane to remove every single one manually (specially if you've forgotten what most of them are called via apt-get)! Bleachbit sounds good, will check!

Comment: @KarlMorrison obviously not :) - so just use `autoremove`

Comment: It might be a misspelling but you typed `apt-get remove`, were you meaning `apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: @KarlMorrison my mistake - sorry **:)**

Answer (score 2):

yes you may use `apt-get autoremove` to get rid those.  But with term that dependencies was installed  via `apt-get` command.

If those dependencies are installed manually from tarball or source, then no other way you need to remove it manually.